# spring messages.properties uses variable name

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to use a title instead of a variable name when overriding Spring's default messages using the messages.properties file?

For example, I used this

```
typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer={0} must be a number.
```

to create the error message "firstName must be a number.", but I would prefer more readability, like "First Name must be a number.".

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the property for a specific field of a specific class. Say your model attribute is named *foo* and it has a property named *firstName* then you can declare a custom error message for that specific field using:

```
typeMismatch.foo.firstName=First Name must be a number
```

You can see [this page](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html) for more information.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks Alex.

Comment: Had to laugh when I looked back at the question and realized first names are not typically numbers...

Comment: Yes i noticed the same and was tempted to tell you but hey, maybe you're designing forms for robots that are named after numbers ;-)